# Azure B2C Forgot Password Flow on Self Asserted Page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are changing our log in experience to a different style user journey. We will not be asking for the password right away, and instead will be collecting the Email at the beginning and doing a validation check.

However, we still want to have a forgot password link on the page.

In our Sign IN Policy I have this..

(This is super early on in development so yes... its giving a token right away)

```
<UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignIn">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ValidateAccount" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountLookup" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!--Issue an access token-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
```

However the forgot password link does not appear.

This is done in a self asserted page, and im guessing you cant do the forgot password link on that page?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange"/>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="ValidateAccount"/>
    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ValidateAccount" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountLookup"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>objectId</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword"/>      
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using the CombinedSignInAndSignUp on the main page since it is only collected the email. But I will try this.

Comment: Hi. I get a Claim not verified: [Email Address] error on clicking Forgot Password. Would this fix it or bring me closer to the solution?